# How can I have an optional TypeVar in a Generic class in Python?

Tags: python, generics, mypy, python-typing, typing

I'm trying to write a simple type wrapper to represent the interface of decorator functions:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Generic

TIn = TypeVar('TIn', contravariant=True)
TOut = TypeVar('TOut', covariant=True)

class Decorator(Protocol, Generic[TIn, TOut]):
    """
    Represents a decorated value, used to simplify type definitions
    """
    def __call__(self, value: TIn) -> TOut:
        ...
```

This would be used to type a decorator function as follows:

```
IntFunction = Callable[[int, int], int]


def register_operator(op: str) -> Decorator[IntFunction, IntFunction]:
    def inner(value: IntFunction) -> IntFunction:
        # register the function or whatever
        return value
    return inner


@register_operator("+")
def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    return a + b
```

In the above example, Mypy is able to validate the type signature of `add` to ensure it matches the specification of `register_operator`.

This is useful for decorators that transform the type (eg converting it from an `IntFunction` to a `StrFunction`), but in almost all cases, `TIn` is identical to `TOut`, and so I want to simplify the usage of my definition.

Essentially, I want to make it so that if `TOut` isn't given, it will be assumed to be the same as `TIn`, which would allow the above decorator function to be simplified to

```py
def register_operator(op: str) -> Decorator[IntFunction]:
    #                              Simplification here ^

    def inner(value: IntFunction) -> IntFunction:
        # register the function or whatever
        return value
    return inner
```

The ideal syntax I would use in my protocol definition would be something like this:

```py
class Decorator(Protocol, Generic[TIn, TOut = TIn]):
    """
    Represents a decorated value, used to simplify type definitions
    """
    def __call__(self, value: TIn) -> TOut:
        ...
```

Note that this does not work.

How can I achieve this functionality, whilst continuing to have the assurance that Mypy provides? I am happy to make the definition of `Decorator` as complex as needed, but I want to keep its simple usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far I know python doesn't support default values in generics, a generic that isn't fully defined becomes unknown. Perhaps it should support it, there's a draft pep for this feature (see update below).

For now, I would create two classes that expose different interfaces. This is almost as good, it just means you need a second class:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Generic, overload

TIn = TypeVar('TIn', contravariant=True)
TOut = TypeVar('TOut', covariant=True)
TSym = TypeVar('TSym')

class Decorator(Protocol, Generic[TIn, TOut]):
    """
    Represents a decorated value, used to simplify type definitions
    """
    def __call__(self, value: TIn) -> TOut:
        ...

class SymmetricDecorator(Decorator[TSym,TSym], Generic[TSym], Protocol):
    pass
```

By "Symmetric" I just mean the callable receives and returns the same type - there might be a better name. Hope this is useful!

**UPDATE:** I've since found there exists an active pep for default values for TypeVar: https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/